# Nested resources error: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resources, nested

I'm trying to use nested resources in Rails 4 but getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError (Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Client::Website::ClientWebsitesController)
```

So I have a client model which is created by devise and I got a website model. The relationship is one to many.

Database:

```
    create_table(:clients) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  t.timestamps
end

    create_table :websites do |t|
  t.string :host
  t.string :name
  t.text :description
  t.text :code #integration code, that field will be filled after the website is created
  t.integer :client_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

Models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :websites
  has_many :partner_profits
  belongs_to :subscription_plan
end

class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    has_many :questions
    has_one :popup_skin
end
```

routes:

```
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :partners
  devise_for :clients

    resources :clients do
        resources :websites, controller: 'client/website/client_websites'
    end

  root to: 'frontend#index'
```

I never used nested resources before, any ideas what am I missing here? Trying to resolve the problem for a second day already :(

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: I'd imagine the problem will be with your `Client::Website::ClientWebsitesController` file

This is a controller - are you sure it's set up correctly? 

Also, you should really provide the code for this controller & the view / controller you're referencing it from (these will show you any issues you may have in calling it)

Comment: That particular error message will sometimes appear when the problem has nothing to do with dependencies at all - see this issue for discussion: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12394

You'll want to check the controller file for other errors (references to constants that don't exist are common triggers). Post it here if you still can't turn anything up.

Comment: @MattJones Thanks. This led me to find a typo in the name of my model class.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may be happening (though I can't see it here) is that you may be referencing classes directly in their superclasses.

I had this problem, and fixed it like this:

```
class SDMObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  # simplified for example
  LOCAL_CLASSES = [Tenant] # WRONG! Causes circular dependency
  LOCAL_CLASSES = ['Tenant'] # OK! Just evaluate to the class when needed
end

class Tenant < SDMObject
end
```